# Как из массива сделать черно-белую картинку в png?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, обработка-изображений

Как из массива который состоит из 0 и 1, сделать черно-белую картинку?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм:

1. Создайте пиксельный numpy.array нужной вам размерности
2. воспользуйтесь [PIL.Image.fromarray()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)
3. опционально: сохранить полученное изображение как PNG файл, воспользовавшись методом [Image.save()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)